# What is the MariaDB dialect class name for Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, mariadb

In **Hibenate** I am using **MariaDB** but I couldn't find the dialect class name of **MariaDB** .

In Hibernate, MySQL5 dialect's name is

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

For Oracle 10g

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```

What is the dialect class name for **MariaDB**?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As [announced here](https://planet.jboss.org/post/mariadb_dialects), starting with Hibernate ORM 5.2.8 (around Feb 15, 2017), the dialects

`org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect`

and

`org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`

are available. The announcement concludes that

> If you are using MariaDB, it’s best to use the MariaDB-specific
>   Dialects from now on since it’s much easier to match the MariaDB
>   version with its appropriate Hibernate Dialect.

Comment: What dialect to use when using hibernate 5.1?

Answer (score 62):

## Update note: Hibernate automatic dialect resolution

In older versions of Hibernate, you are required to specify the dialect. But starting with version 3.2, hibernate uses [dialect resolution](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#portability-dialectresolver) to automatically determine the target database and the dialect that should be used.

The [Hibernate 5.0 userguide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect) says:

> **In most cases** Hibernate will be able to determine the proper Dialect to use by asking some questions of the JDBC Connection during bootstrap.

> If for some reason it is not able to determine the proper one or you want to use a custom Dialect, you will need to set the hibernate.dialect setting.

[Hibernate 6.3 userguide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect) even discourages you to set the property:

> In Hibernate 6, it’s **no longer necessary** to explicitly specify a dialect using the configuration property hibernate.dialect, and so setting that property **is now discouraged**. (An exception is the case of custom user-written Dialects.)

The [Hibernate 6.3 api doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/JdbcSettings.html#DIALECT) says:

> As of Hibernate 6, this property should not be explicitly specified, except when using a custom user-written implementation of Dialect. Instead, applications **should allow Hibernate to select the Dialect automatically**.

## Very short answer

Updated answer (Oct 05, 2023):

- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDBDialect** for MariaDB server **10.3 and later**

Update: some of these classes are now deprecated or even removed:

- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDB106Dialect** for MariaDB server **10.6 and later**, provides skip locked support.
- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDB103Dialect** for MariaDB server **10.3 and later**, provides sequence support.
- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDB102Dialect** for MariaDB server **10.2**
- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDB10Dialect** for MariaDB server **10.0 and 10.1**
- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDB53Dialect** for MariaDB server **5.3, and later 5.x versions**.
- org.hibernate.dialect.**MariaDBDialect** for MariaDB server **5.1 and 5.2**.

## Short answer

When using a MariaDB server, you should **use MariaDB Connector/J and MariaDB Hibernate dialects, not the MySQL ones**. Even though MariaDB was created as a drop-in replacement and even though basic features will likely work when using the MySQL versions of those, subtle problems may occur or you may miss certain features.

A complete list of available MariaDB dialects are currently not mentioned in the Hibernate User Guide, but in the [Hibernate JavaDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html). **Depending on your MariaDB server version, you should select the corresponding dialect version**. The current dialects as of this writing are:

- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB102Dialect for MariaDB server 10.2
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect for MariaDB server 10.3 and later, provides sequence support.
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB10Dialect for MariaDB server 10.0 and 10.1
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect for MariaDB server 5.3, and later 5.x versions.
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect for MariaDB server 5.1 and 5.2.

Note that for detailed usage information, you'll sometimes have to look in dialect source codes. (There are non-JavaDoc usage information comments in some dialect sources.)

If you want to change or explicitly mention the storage engine for the MariaDB dialect, you can use the `storage_engine` Hibernate variable. For example: `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine = innodb`. IMO, you should do this explicitly, because the default can change when switching to a different MariaDB server version.

If you're using a MariaDB server older than 10.1.2 (which doesn't support fractional seconds), then you may want to provide the parameter `useFractionalSeconds=false` to the JDBC URL, otherwise MariaDB Connector/J will not truncate timestamps internally, which can cause time comparison problem when those values are using in comparison queries (even when using plain JDBC), which can cause Hibernate versioning problems and optimistic locking problems for temporal types.

## Long answer

The MariaDB dialect for Hibernate (5.3 as of this writing) is mentioned in the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html). The mentioned dialect "short names" followed by remarks are:

> - MariaDB: Support for the MariadB database. May work with newer versions
> - MariaDB53: Support for the MariadB database, version 5.3 and newer.

However, a complete list of the available official MariaDB dialects can be found in the [Hibernate JavaDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html). Which currently lists:

- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB102Dialect for MariaDB server 10.2
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect for MariaDB server 10.3 and later, provides sequence support.
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB10Dialect for MariaDB server 10.0 and 10.1
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect for MariaDB server 5.3, and later 5.x versions.
- org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect for MariaDB server 5.1 and 5.2.

Each dialect successor inherits the settings from the previous dialect version. So the inheritance hierachy for MariaDB is: `MariaDB103Dialect > MariaDB102Dialect > MariaDB10Dialect > MariaDB53Dialect > MariaDBDialect > MySQL5Dialect > MySQLDialect > Dialect`

MariaDB was designed as a drop-in replacement for MySQL. But the databases are likely going to diverge as time goes by. Most basic features probably work without problems, allowing you to swap Connector/J clients (MariaDB client on MySQL server and vice versa), and allow you to swap dialects (MySQL dialect on MariaDB client and vice versa). But there are subtle differences that may cause unexpected problems. For example, the MySQL Connector/J client contains hardcoded checks for the server version, which will fail when using a MariaDB server, causing some features to be disabled in the client, such as the MySQL sendFractionalSeconds client parameter. This will cause fractional seconds to be disabled, so then the fractions will be truncated in the MySQL client but not in the MariaDB client. (This may even lead to optimistic locking problems when using versioning with date/time types in combination with non-max precision SQL date/time types. In these cases, use the max precision of 6.)

Also, the MariaDB dialect are expected to provide specific functionality for MariaDB:
http://in.relation.to/2017/02/16/mariadb-dialects/

> In time, we will add new Dialects based on newer capabilities
> introduced by MariaDB.

> If you are using MariaDB, it’s best to use the MariaDB-specific
> Dialects from now on since it’s much easier to match the MariaDB
> version with its appropriate Hibernate Dialect.

And https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11457 says:

> since MySQL and MariaDB have gone in different directions, we might
> want to provide MariaDB Dialects as well.
>
> For instance, it's not very intuitive for a Hibernate user to figure
> out that they need to use the MySQLInnoDb57Dialect to handle
> Timestamps with microsecond precision which have been available since
> MariaDB 5.3:

The Hibernate User Guide doesn't provide all usage information about how to use the dialects. Even the User Guide combines with the API docs may not be enough. Sometimes you'll have to look in the source codes for usage information. For example, [MariaDB53Dialect.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MariaDB53Dialect.java) contains hidden non-JavaDoc comments that may be useful.

Previously, to select a MySQL storage engine, such as MyISAM or InnoDB or default, you could switch between for example `MySQL57InnoDBDialect` and `MySQL57Dialect`. But they refactored the MySQL dialect hierarchy starting from Hibernate 5.2.8, as mentioned in a [Hibernate blog post](http://in.relation.to/2017/02/20/mysql-dialect-refactoring/). Note that to select a storage engine, you should use a Environment Variable or System Property: `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine`. For example: `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine = innodb`.

XtraDB was the default MariaDB storage engine for MariaDB 10.1 and earlier, but since 10.2 it's InnoDB. So there may be cases that you want to explicitly mention the storage engine that Hibernate selects, so then you'll have to use the `storage_engine` variable. Info about the `storage_engine` variable (which isn't mentioned in the User Guide), can be found in the source of [`AvailableSettings.java`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.3/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java).

If you're using a MariaDB server older than 10.1.2 (which doesn't support fractional seconds), then you may want to provide the parameter `useFractionalSeconds=false` to the JDBC URL, otherwise MariaDB Connector/J will not truncate timestamps internally, which can cause time comparison problem, which can cause Hibernate versioning problems and optimistic locking problems for temporal types.

Comment: Great answer! But try and fix its title ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this the same for `NHibernate` too?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://sterl.org/2015/09/spring-boot-mariadb/), it was mentioned 
"it needs to be the MySQL5InnoDBDialect or MySQL57InnoDBDialect instead of the MySQLInnoDBDialect"

For complete list, see
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect

New MariaDB dialect is added in 5.2.17. See [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11769) and [commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/eed7f70751db31a3f02cdf192e070edf8156f695)

Comment: Note that this answer is outdated and not correct anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Mysql5Dialect, because MariaDB is compatible with mysql.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/#incompatibilities-between-mariadb-55-and-mysql-55

Comment: This is just not true!

Comment: MariaDB is obviously not compatible with mysql.

Comment: @FrancisNiu as you can see the answer is from 2016 in this year the dbms was compatible.