# How to specify utf8 encoding for db and tables, using embedded database MariaDB in Spring application?

Tags: spring, mariadb, in-memory-database

Developing web application I'd like to use an embedded database to store data. However instead of proposed in-memory databases I`d like to prefer to use custom one. My choice is MariaDB. I have been ruled with [this](https://objectpartners.com/2017/06/19/using-mariadb4j-for-a-spring-boot-embedded-database/) article how to get MariaDB as embedded database in my project, everything is fine, database appears, except one thing: I cannot change an encoding for my tables values.

I tried to set additional application properties in my application.yml file, tried to complete connection string with parameters of specifying encoding, but all those stuff didn't work unfortunately :(
May any of you have ever faced with such problem and can help me? Thank you in advance!

My current application.yml is following:

```
mariaDB4j:
  dataDir: ./localMariaDB
  port: 3307
  databaseName: embeddedDB
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariaDB://localhost:3307/
    username: root
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

And finally I get exception bellow:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x92 \xD1\x80\xD0...' for column 'current_status' at row 1
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1688) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.6.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1550) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.6.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1513) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.6.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:318) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.6.2.jar:na]
... 121 common frames omitted
```

By the way, when I run the application, the connection string which I get looks like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/embeddedDB`.
I am confused why there is `:mysql:` instead of `:mariadb:` as specified in my connection properties. Does it have an influence on my database behavior?

Comment: MariaDB is a MySQL fork. It's possible that the "mysql" constant has stuck around in some places (intentionally or not).

Comment: @JoachimSauer, so it is not a big deal that such changes appear and they don`t influence for database, right?

Comment: I don't think it's an issue, but switching to the [Hibernate MariadDB dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066024/what-is-the-mariadb-dialect-class-name-for-hibernate) might be a good idea.

Comment: @JoachimSauer your advice may be good idea, but not a question resolution( nothing happened..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have found the resolution to my issue.
It appeared as usual very simple :)
To change standard character encoding, which MariaDB proposes, I had to specify additional configuration properties before setting up the MariaDB's `DataSource`.
As [this](https://objectpartners.com/2017/06/19/using-mariadb4j-for-a-spring-boot-embedded-database/) source provides to configure `MariaDBSpringService` entity to further use in `DataSource`configuration, it is necessary to extend it (`MariaDBSpringService`) with some character encoding description utils. So, to specify custom encoding (i.e. to change standard one) I've just added the following lines of code to `MariaDBSpringService` bean:

```
service.getConfiguration().addArg("--character-set-server=utf8mb4");
service.getConfiguration().addArg("--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci");
```

In general, the full bean declaration is below:

```
@Bean
public MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService(){
    MariaDB4jSpringService service = new MariaDB4jSpringService();
    service.getConfiguration().addArg("--character-set-server=utf8mb4");
    service.getConfiguration().addArg("--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci");
    return service;
}
```

Hope, this will help somebody, who further can possibly face with such issue))
Thanks to everybody, who tried to help me!